# i want to execute argument in loop

Tags: wordpress

```
    if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$field,true) && $field == 'is_this_a_job' )
      {

    $today = date('Ymd');   
      $args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'meta_key'          => 'last_date',
     'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: You may write custom query for that.

Comment: query is running in my code before this

Comment: Please add the complete code and the result you wanted